# How can I use TweenLite to implement effect of Flex's PopUpManager?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How can I use TweenLite to implement   effect   of Flex's PopUpManager?

Answer (score 1):

I am using [greensock tweenlite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) for sample

here a code for creating simple **tweenlite effect** on popup using **PopUpManager**

```
        import com.greensock.TweenLite;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import mx.containers.TitleWindow;

        [Bindable]
        private var titleWindow:TitleWindow;


        private function createTweenlitePopup():void{
        titleWindow=TitleWindow(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,TitleWindow,true));
        titleWindow.title = "This is my title window";


        TweenLite.to(titleWindow, 1.5, {x:100}); 
        }
```

and button calling **createTweenlitePopup()** to create popup is

```
<mx:Button click="{createPopup()}"/>
```

Hopes that helps